Is "Ita an non" a valid, neutral, straightfoward translation of "Yes or no"?
Asking to really, really be sure since I'm planning on getting it tattoed. I just intend that simple sentence in the more correctly latin way possible, but there are many ways to say it and I don't completly understand. Yes or no, sim ou não, sí o no, ita an non?
Thank you!

You have to start by deciding what “Yes or no” means. It could be a demand for a clear answer (“did you take my chocolate? Yes or no?”). Or it could be an expression of not wanting to give a specific answer to a question - I won’t say yes, I won’t say no, I just say “Yes or no”.

I don't know whether this is relevant to your question or not (I'm not sure I understand it per the comment of @MartinKochanski ) but Peter Abelard wrote a famous book called Sic et Non in the 12th century, which means "yes and no".

@Martin furthermore, "yes" being frequently an affirmative statement, such as the example of "etiam" in the answer, you have to know what the question is: one would say "yes" differently depending on whether it is about having something, going somewhere, being in some state, etc.

I think your expression is good and straightforward. Some notes concerning this idea...
If we are talking classical Latin, Romans did not say "yes" quite the same way we do and they usually used more oblique ways of saying it. For example:
proin tu uel aias uel neges ("Tell me either you say it, or you don't say it") --Plautus, The Rope. Here, the force of the expression is the speaker is asking for a yes or no answer.
Cicero wrote ...aut ‘etiam’ aut ‘non’ respondere possit ("He can answer yes or no").
In the Attic Nights, somewhat later Latin, it says: ...aut plus aut aliter... which literally means "either more or otherwise", but has the force of meaning Yes or No.
In the pseudo Quintillian at one point the author writes: Dic utrum. ("Tell me whether [or not]".) which is a very elegant way to ask the question "Yes or No". Notice how Romans usually say ait or dic (tell me / speak), they don't just say "yes or no?" the way we would in most cases.
Ausonius (a later author) writes vel non o certa.
